# Android install API 13 Failure

Tags: android, windows, api, sdk

I use Game Maker Studio and as I bought a new computer I nedeed to reinstall all tools for Android development. Game Maker Studio need API 13 to work but SDK manager refuses to install it. Se in the anexed image. What's wrong with repositories or whatever ? [SKD refuses to install APi13(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBMO.png)

As you can see, it says "Not compatible with Windows" and only allow me to install Google Api....

Answer (score 0):

Try to install api 13 by third party.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer to the question

Comment: 50 reputation required, don't have it.